# Function is equal to its own derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We all know that derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$. Is exponential function only function that has such property? If yes how to prove that there are no other functions. If no, what are other functions? Help me please

Comment: I can't add another answer, but it's also true without having to go to ODE theory:
If f(x) is a function equal to its own derivative, then
$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)e^{-x}] = f'(x)e^{-x} - f(x)e^{-x}= 0$$
Thus $f(x)e^{-x}$ is a constant $C$, or
$$f = Ce^{x}$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seek to solve the ODE $y'=y$ for arbitrary boundary conditions. This is separable and yields
$$1 = \frac y{y'}$$
Integration gives
$$x+c = \ln(y(x))$$
or
$$y(x)=e^{x+c} = e^c e^x = \tilde c e^x$$
The uniqueness is guaranteed by Picard-Lindelöf.

Comment: Isn't f(x)=0 also its own derivative, even though there is no c such that e^c=0?

Comment: @JarredAllen Yes but that means $y'=0$ so the separation was already invalid in this special case. Additionally, $y < 0$ needs to be dealt with by premultiplying with $-1$. In the end these cases can be dealt with by allowing $\tilde c\in \mathbb R$ instead of $\tilde c > 0$ in the general solution.